# Used rangedbeacon.setSampleExpritation() but it makes the getdistance() imprecise

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

I'm using the altbeacon library to implement an indoor navigation application using ibks beacons, but my problem is that I want a fast scan so I used the setSampleExpiration method and set it to 10 seconds, but now the distances are imprecise. How can I have a good precision with a faster scan ?

Answer (score 0):

When using Bluetooth LE to get distance estimates **there is always a tradeoff between accuracy and the number of statistical samples**.  Because there is a lot of noise on RSSI, you need lots of samples to filter it out.

Reducing the sampling time from the default of 20 seconds to 10 seconds will make estimates change more quickly, but at the cost of this accuracy.

One thing you can do is **increase the number of signal measurements.**  If you can increase the advertising rate on the ibks beacon (for example from 1 Hz to 10 Hz) then you will have more samples and get better estimates.